# Is STL empty() threadsafe?

Tags: stl, thread-safety

I have multiple threads modifying an stl vector and an stl list.
I want to avoid having to take a lock if the container is empty

Would the following code be threadsafe?  What if items was a list or a map?

```
class A  
{  
    vector<int> items  
    void DoStuff()  
    {  
        if(!items.empty())  
        {  
            AquireLock();  
            DoStuffWithItems();  
            ReleaseLock();  
        }  
     }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the responses. To clarify the question:
Another thread will add to items.  No other thread will remove from items -- removes will only happen inside DoStuffWithItems() and only a single thread calls DoStuff().
Its okay if items.empty() returns false while another thread is adding to it.  Its not okay if items.empty() causes the application to crash if another thread is adding to it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends what you expect. The other answers are right that *in general*, standard C++ containers are not thread-safe, and furthermore, that *in particular* your code doesn’t ward against another thread modifying the container between your call to `empty` and the acquisition of the lock (but this matter is unrelated to the thread safety of `vector::empty`).

So, to ward off any misunderstandings: **Your code does not guarantee `items` will be non-empty inside the block.**

But your code can still be useful, since all you want to do is avoid redundant lock creations. Your code doesn’t give guarantees but it *may* prevent an unnecessary lock creation. It won’t work in all cases (other threads can still empty the container between your check and the lock) but in *some* cases. And if all you’re after is an optimization by omitting a redundant lock, then your code accomplishes that goal.

Just make sure that any actual *access* to the container *is* protected by locks.

By the way, **the above is *strictly speaking* undefined behaviour**: an STL implementation is theoretically allowed to modify `mutable` members inside the call to `empty`. This would mean that the apparently harmless (because read-only) call to `empty` *can* actually cause a conflict. Unfortunately, you *cannot* rely on the assumption that read-only calls are safe with STL containers.

In practice, though, I am pretty sure that `vector::empty` will *not* modify *any* members. But already for `list::empty` I am less sure. If you really want *guarantees*, then either lock *every* access or don’t use the STL containers.

Answer (score 3):

There is no thread-safe guaranty on anything in the containers and algorithms of the the STL.

So, No.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of whether or not empty is thread safe, your code will not, as written, accomplish your goal.

```
class A  
{  
    vector<int> items  
    void DoStuff()  
    {  
        if(!items.empty())  
        {  
            //Another thread deletes items here.
            AquireLock();  
            DoStuffWithItems();  
            ReleaseLock();  
        }  
     }  
}
```

A better solution is to lock every time you work with `items` (when iterating, getting items, adding items, checking count/emptiness, etc.), thus providing your own thread safety.  So, acquire the lock first, **then** check if the vector is empty.

Comment: Your point (//Another thread deletes items here.) is clear. Yet it is also obvious that you can check empty() after acquiring the lock in order to be sure.

Comment: @skwllsp: A valid point.  If `empty()` is thread safe, checking empty first, locking, and then rechecking may avoid an unnecessary lock.

Answer (score 2):

As it is already answered, the above code is not thread safe and locking is mandatory before actually doing anything with the container.
But the following should have better performance than always locking and I can't think of a reason that it can be unsafe.
The idea here is that locking can be expensive and we are avoiding it, whenever not really needed.

```
class A
{
    vector<int> items;  
    void DoStuff()  
    {  
        if(!items.empty())  
        {  
            AquireLock();
            if(!items.empty())
            {
                DoStuffWithItems();  
            }
            ReleaseLock();  
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Suppose that `empty()` required checking a value in the allocated block, but that block was reallocated by another thread during the call.  That would make `empty()` itself unsafe.  It would take careful design with atomic operations to make it safe, and no guarantee that the next revision of the library wouldn't change it to unsafe again.

Comment: I am trying to understand what will go wrong in that case.

In case another thread is inserting into the container, then this check may return true, instead of false, right?

Thus we may miss an iteration of a loop, but the next iteration that does not have a race with another thread will eventually work as expected.

Am I missing something important?

Comment: If doing the empty check requires using a pointer to allocated memory, and the other thread causes that pointer to be invalidated, you could not just get the wrong answer but blow up the program completely.

Answer (score 1):

STL is not thread safe and empty too. If you want make container safe you must close all its methods by mutex or other sync